# Read messages sent in Discord chat using C # ( without using a discord bot )

Tags: c#, discord

I wanted to see if there is a way to receive new messages that are sent in the Discord chat ? In fact,I need this to happen in a Discord account, not a robot.
thanks

Comment: Why does it have to be without a bot? Discord bots and APIs are literally intended for this exact purpose. I suppose you could use write and Optical Character Recognition program and have it look at your screen if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Discord.Net **2.0** user tokens disallowed for usage with API. It was announced at Discord GitHub [here](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/issues/827). As *@Jeff Chen* said, Discord **Bots** provided for that purposes. So I highly recommend you to deal with bots and get the desired result.